# Screen locked on desktop resize (aarch64 virtual machine)

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, lock-screen, qemu

I use Ubuntu 22.10 (and used all previous versions) in various environments, mostly virtual machines. I just ran into a new unexpected and annoying behavior on aarch64 (64-bit Arm).

When I resize the desktop (i.e. the virtual machine window), the screen lock is immediately activated and I must enter the user's password to continue.

The new environment is a Mac M1 (aarch64) with qemu virtualization and UTM frontend. Ubuntu 22.10 has just been installed in the VM with Ubuntu Desktop. Everything else works fine. The virtual environment integration is functional (display, copy/paste, shared folder). The desktop resize is correctly handled, except that it also triggers a screen lock.

I do not think that this is entirely kvm or qemu's fault because screen lock is a desktop application feature.

Since this is a test VM, the security of the machine usage is left to the host. In the Ubuntu guest: auto-login on boot, screen saver and screen lock are deactivated. Screen lock never happens, except on desktop resize in the virtual machines.

In all other environments I use (VirtualBox on Windows Intel, Parallels on macOS Intel), with the same Ubuntu settings (auto-login, screen lock deactivated), no screen lock appear on desktop resize.

Could it be an issue specific to aarch64?